# Convert PDF pages to images with COCOA

Tags: cocoa, pdf, split

I am having problem with PDF conversion to images. I would like to create an image file for every page in PDF document.

This is the code I am using and works fine. Every page gets converted into the image, but I have problem with image resolution. I don't know how to set the resolution of the output images. Can someone help me out?

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/test/test.pdf"]];


NSPDFImageRep *img = [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithData:pdfData]; 
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 int count = [img pageCount]; 
 for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) { 
  [img setCurrentPage:i]; 
  NSImage *temp = [[NSImage alloc] init]; 
  [temp addRepresentation:img]; 
  NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[temp TIFFRepresentation]]; 
  NSData *finalData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil]; 
  NSString *pageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%d.jpg", [img currentPage]]; 
  [fileManager createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"/Users/mac/Desktop/", pageName] contents:finalData attributes:nil];
 }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since NSPDFImageRep is a subclass of NSImageRep, couldn't you use the [NSImageRep drawInRect:] method?

Link: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000346-drawInRect_

Comment: I don't think that would work since I need to call [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithData:pdfData], which creates and returns an NSPDFImageRep object initialized with the specified PDF data. 

If I would use [NSImageRep drawInRect:], how would I get PDF page to draw into this rect?

Comment: For me it looks like this approach is working fine. This is the code:

        NSRect bounds = pdfImageRep.bounds;
        CGFloat factor = 4.;
        NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, bounds.size.width * factor, bounds.size.height * factor);
        NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rect.size];
        [image lockFocus];
        [pdfImageRep drawInRect:rect];
        [image unlockFocus];

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use the ImageIO framework. Feed the PDF data to an [image source](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html) to get a [CGImage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html); feed that object to an [image destination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html) to generate (and optionally save in the same step) the JPEG data. In the latter step, you can specify the resolution among the image properties; see [“Individual Image Properties” in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Individual_Image_Properties).

Don't forget to [finalize your destination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationFinalize). It's vital.